# Why does the IMG element have the CSS color property?

Tags: css, image

Why on earth does the IMG element have the CSS color property?

After playing around in Firebug for 20 minutes, I couldn't figure out how it could be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will color the alt text when a picture fails to load: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YbZnA/).

Comment: Now, of course. If you're a web bot or blind, does color really matter? :D

Answer (score 4):

`IMG` is no different than any other inline element. For instance, in most browsers, the color attribute sets the color of the alt text while the image is loading or when it can't otherwise be rendered.

Comment: Hmmm, me thinks StackOverflow has some caching bugs to squash. I saw Dennis' answer before yours showed up, even though it's telling me now that yours came in first.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    img {
        color: #f00;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #000;
        position: absolute;
    }
    img:after {
        content: "asdf";
    }
<style>

<img />
```

`asdf` is red. (on Firefox, tested with firebug on this very page.)

Anyways, I'm pretty sure the CSS standard doesn't bind particular CSS rules to particular HTML tag elements.

Comment: Oh well, I can't believe I missed the `alt` text case. Haha.

Comment: No worries. Your answer was still educational, albeit not exactly what I was trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Every element has every property, though some properties do not “apply to”, i.e. cannot have effect on, some elements (see clause [Applies to](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#applies-to) in the CSS spec.). So the question is really this: Under which circumstances could the `color` property affect the rendering of an `img` element? As described in other answers, it could affect the rendering of alternative text or generated content. (In old browsers, though, `alt` text may be rendered using fixed routines that are immune to CSS rules.)